# Range in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a function MyRange as follows:

**Input:** three numbers a,b,d
**Output:** an array of values from a to b with step size of d.

For example, if A1 contains 1, and B1 contains 5, and you write =MyRange(A1,B1,1) in the cell C1 (and you type Ctrl+Shift+Enter) you get:

```
 A | B | C | D | E | F | G
 -------------------------
 1 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

Here's my trial:

```
Function MyRange(a, b, d)  
Dim Index As Integer, Number As Integer  
Dim Res() As Integer  
Index = 0  
For Number = a To b Step d  
   Res(Index) = Number
   Index = Index + 1  
Next Number
MyRange = Res
End Function
```

When I try this, Excel throws #VALUE! and I don't know what's the problem..

BTW yeah, I had a similar question before that got no answer, as it was too complicated, so I'd deleted it and simplified my question here.

Comment: this isn't full answer, but one thing you'll need to do to get your output is select `C1:C[B+2]` and enter the array formula with all these columns highlighted to get your output.

Comment: Are you entering it as an array formula? You are also not declaring the size of Res so need to use Redim.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman tnx, but even when I do it, Excel throws the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of cleanup worked for me. Mainly, I adding the `ReDim Preserve` to keep adding dimensions to the array.

```
Function MyRange(a As Integer, b As Integer, d As Integer) As Integer()

    Dim Index As Integer, Number As Integer
    Dim Res() As Integer

    Index = 0

    For Number = a To b Step d

        ReDim Preserve Res(Index)
        Res(Index) = Number
        Index = Index + 1

    Next Number

    MyRange = Res

End Function
```

The problem you will have is with how many columns to select over from C to enter your formula. This will depend on `d/b`.

Comment: how could I generalize it to handle the case where a,b,d are Integer() rather than just Integer?

Comment: @DudiFrid -  if you want to pass array's into the arguments write `(a() as Integer, b() as Integer ...)`